# Get name and location in the permissions ["NAME", "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"] in the google assistant

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm asking for name and location permissions in the google assistant, using the following json format as responses from the webhook

```
    "payload": {
"google": {
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "systemIntent": {
    "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
    "data": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
      "optContext": "Hello",
      "permissions": [
        "NAME",
        "DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

In the next "attempt" of dialogflow as I retrieve the name and location obtained? I read something about `originalDetectIntentRequest`  Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some client to develop Dialogflow/AoG webhook.
If you are only concerned with Action on Google for Google Assistant, you could use [Actions-On-Google Node Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) to build webhook.
If you want to expand the bot to other platforms in the future, use [Dialogflow-Fulfillment Node client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment).
This way it would be better to access parameters, session data, contexts compared to JSON.

Coming back to your question, check out the [following link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#json). You will also need to create a separate intent in Dialogflow that would accept the following event "`actions_intent_PERMISSION`" to capture the result of the user permission. In this intent, you will need to process for the response depending on the user's reply for permission request.
you will get something similar to the following JSON:

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "yes"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "PERMISSION",
          "rawText": "yes",
          "textValue": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Here is the [link to GitHub examples](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-helper-intents-nodejs/blob/master/functions/helper-intents/ask-for-permission.js).

Hope this help!